# How to access Slack's Interactive Message request payload parameter?

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I would like to access the payload parameter sent by Slack to Interactive Message Request Url when a user clicks on a button in one of these messages.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your server side, check your request url route is allowed to receive POST. 
As said in theirs docs (https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) :

> Your Action URL will receive a HTTP POST request, including a payload
>   body parameter, itself containing an application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   JSON string.

You first have to decode the **x-www-form-urlencoded** format of the request, then **json** decode it.

In python, I end up with this line of code :

```
payload = json.loads(urlparse.parse_qs(request.get_data())['payload'][0])
```

Hope it helps someone else one day !

Comment: and use `urllib.parse.parse_qs(request.get_data().decode())` in Python3

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AWS lamdba as backend, use following. (python3)

```
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

payload = json.loads(parse_qs(event['body'])['payload'][0])
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed getting the info this way:

```
data = request.form.to_dict()
payload = json.loads(data['payload'])
print(payload["actions"][0]["name"])
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

The first line converts the ImmutableDict to a mutable dictionary.

The second line is necessary because the payload is still JSON.

The third line is simply accessing the payload action details as seen in the [Block Link Builder](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/), often most people will only have one relevant action to process.

Comment: This has helped me....thank you very much. btw the last closing bracket on the 3rd line should be on the 2nd line